# C# Windows Forms and MVVN - how is it correct?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm

Good afternoon. I am making an application on Windows Forms. Because I am mentally preparing for the transition to WPF and MVVM, I decided to first try this pattern in a familiar environment. I ask you to evaluate how well I handle bindings and asynchronous methods.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        ViewModel vm;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //----bindings
            vm = new ViewModel();
            vm.Message += (s, msg) => MessageBox.Show(msg);
            tbArchieve.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", vm, "ArchieveName", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
            tbDestinationFolder.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", vm, "DestinationFolder", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
            btStart.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", vm, "Ready"));
            pbExtraction.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", vm, "Progress"));
            
        }
 
        private void btBrowseFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                dialog.Filter = "Архивы|*.7z;*.rar;*.zip";
                if(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    vm.ArchieveName = dialog.FileName;
                }
            }
        }
 
        private void btBrowserDistrination_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                dialog.SelectedPath = Application.ExecutablePath;
                if(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    vm.DestinationFolder = dialog.SelectedPath;
                }
            }
        }
 
        private void btStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            vm.Start();
        }
```

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
 
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public event EventHandler<string> Message;
 
        private void OnPropertyChanged(params string[] props)
        {
            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p)); 
            }
        }
 
        public ViewModel()
        {
            _destinationFolder = string.Empty;
            _archieveName = string.Empty;
        }
 
        #region Поля для формы
 
        string _archieveName;
        public string ArchieveName
        {
            get
            { return _archieveName; }
            set
            {
                if(_archieveName!= value)
                {
                    _archieveName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ArchieveName","Ready");
                }
            }
        }
 
        string _destinationFolder;
        public string DestinationFolder
        {
            get
            { return _destinationFolder; }
            set
            {
                if (_destinationFolder != value)
                {
                    _destinationFolder = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("DestinationFolder", "Ready");
                }
            }
        }
 
        int _progress;
        public int Progress
        {
            get
            {
                return _progress;
            }
            set
            {
                if(_progress!=value)
                {
                    _progress = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Progress");
                }
            }
        }
 
        public bool Ready
        {
            get
            {
                if(File.Exists(_archieveName))
                {
                    if(IsValidPath(_destinationFolder))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
 
        private bool IsValidPath(string path)
        {
            var empty = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path);
            var wrongsyms = path.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '<', '>', '?', '*' }) != -1;
            if (empty || wrongsyms)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
 
        #endregion
 
        public async void Start()
        {
            Unpacker unpacker = new Unpacker(_archieveName);
            unpacker.FileExtracted += (s, ea) => Progress = ea.PercentDone;
            try
            {
                await unpacker.ExtractArchieve(_destinationFolder);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Message.Invoke(this, e.Message);
            }
            
            Message?.Invoke(this, "Архив извлечен!");
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Unpacker
    {
        SevenZipExtractor extractor;
        public async Task ExtractArchieve(string dstFolder)
        {
             await extractor.ExtractArchiveAsync(dstFolder);
        }
 
        public Unpacker(string fileName)
        {
            extractor = new SevenZipExtractor(fileName);
            extractor.FileExtractionFinished += Extractor_FileExtractionFinished;
        }
 
        public event EventHandler<FileInfoEventArgs> FileExtracted;
 
        private void Extractor_FileExtractionFinished(object sender, FileInfoEventArgs e)
        {
            FileExtracted?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }
```

There is also a question - how to do the right thing if the properties in the ViewModel to which the Controls on the form are bound change from the asynchronous method.
Thank you in advance!

I read a lot of examples, but I didn't understand

Comment: It's a mistake to try to use MVVM with WinForms. MVVM was created with WPF in mind, so it doesn't really work with WinForms. If you were to use an MV* pattern in WinForms then MVP would be the most appropriate. Microsoft even created an MVP framework for WinForms in the old Enterprise Library.

Answer (score 0):

Several things get my attention (but honestly, I'm not an expert on this):

```
            //----bindings
            vm = new ViewModel();
            vm.Message += (s, msg) => MessageBox.Show(msg);
            tbArchieve.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", vm, "ArchieveName", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
            // ...
```

You wouldn't normally do this by hand. The WinForms designer has support for data bindings, so you would just put together your bindings in the designer, specifying the type of the view model (which should be made available as a property, hence change your field `vm` to a property).

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is normally implemented like this:

```cs
public class NotifyPropertyChangedCore : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

This allows you to define your properties like this:

```
        string _destinationFolder;
        public string DestinationFolder
        {
            get
            { return _destinationFolder; }
            set
            {
                if (_destinationFolder != value)
                {
                    _destinationFolder = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(); // No need to specify name of own property
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: And if I need to report a change in several properties at once?

Comment: Then you need to explicitly mention them, eg. with `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OtherProperty))` (Always use `nameof()`, this will throw an error if you later rename a property and forget about the call)